# How to read unknown multiple amount of variables and then display them?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to code something that looks like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "type your separated words"
read *all variables*
echo *all variables*
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store them into an array using read

```
read -p $'type your separated words:\n' -a arr
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

Comment: Array is the only way to store multiple unknown vars?

Comment: @ItaiGanot, for an unknown number of vars, this is the only solution I am aware of

Comment: Can you kindly explain what is `"%s\n" "${arr[@]}"` ?

Comment: @ItaiGanot `%s` format the array content as a string and `${arr[@]}` corresponds to all of the array elements.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution :

```
$ read
str1 str2 str3
$ set -- $REPLY
$ echo "$1"
str1
$ echo "$2"
str2
$ echo "$@"
str1 str2 str3
```

But I prefer the 1_CR solution.

Comment: +1 This will work in POSIX shells without array support, as well.